# Vue.js - Dynamically generate v-model name

Tags: javascript, vue.js

this is my first use of Vue.js so please bear with me. I have a section in my app where users can dynamically add (up to 5) entries and also remove entries. Each entry consists of four input tags that correspond to product id, description, quantity, and unit price. There is also an "X" icon at the end so that users can choose whether or not to remove that entry row before saving it. So visually, it would look something like this:

- 1  Tomatoes  40   $2.50  X
- 2  Pears    50 $1.39  X
- 3  Celery 12 $1.60   X

I am unsure how to dynamically generate `v-model` names that correspond to each piece of data that I want to save. In other words, I need four input tags and the X icon for each entry that a user wants to enter. Therefore, I'd want the Vue.js state to look something like:

```
    data: {
        numEntries: 2,
        entries: [
            {
                productId: "",
                description: "",
                qty: "",
                price: "",
            },
            {
                productId: "",
                description: "",
                qty: "",
                price: "",
            },
            // There will be 'n' of these objects depending on how many entries there are.
        ]
    }
```

And I would like the `v-model` to be something like "productId1" to refer to `entries[0].productId` and "productId2" to refer to `entries[1].productId`, etc. My code is shown below:

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
    ...
    <div v-for="n in numEntries" class="inventory-section">
        <input type="text" class="id-input" placeholder="Product Id" v-model="productId" />
        <input type="text" class="description-input" placeholder="Description" v-model="description" />
        <input type="text" class="qty-input" placeholder="Qty" v-model="qty" />
        <input type="text" class="price-input" placeholder="Price" v-model="price" />
        <span class="x-sign" v-on:click="removeEntry">X</span>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

**Vue JS**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        numEntries: 1,
        entries: [
            {
                productId: "",
                description: "",
                qty: "",
                price: "",
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addEntry: function () {
            if (this.numEntries < 12)
                this.numEntries += 1;
        },
        removeEntry: function () {
            if (this.numEntries > 1)
                this.numEntries -= 1;
        }
    }
})
```

In addition, when clicking the `X` on a row, how do I determine which row to remove? Currently my `removeEntry` function is very bare bones.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue loop code:

```
<div v-for="(itm,ind) in entries" class="inventory-section">
    <input type="text" class="id-input" placeholder="Product Id" v-model="itm.productId" />
    <input type="text" class="description-input" placeholder="Description" v-model="itm.description" />
    <input type="text" class="qty-input" placeholder="Qty" v-model="itm.qty" />
    <input type="text" class="price-input" placeholder="Price" v-model="itm.price" />
    <span class="x-sign" @click="removeEntry(ind)">X</span>
    </div>
```

And remove item from array

```
removeEntry: function (i) {
this.entries.splice(i,1)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using v-for="n in numEntries" use it as v-for="entry in entries".
in this way, "entry" will be your scoped object in that div. and you can use v-model="entry.productId"

Answer (score 1):

you can loop through `entries` using `v-for="(entry, index) in entries"`  and you can use `v-model="entry.productId"` and so on

```
   <div id="app">
        ...
        <div v-for="(entry, index) in entries" class="inventory-section">
            <input type="text" class="id-input" placeholder="Product Id" v-model="entry.productId" />
            <input type="text" class="description-input" placeholder="Description" v-model="entry.description" />
            <input type="text" class="qty-input" placeholder="Qty" v-model="entry.qty" />
            <input type="text" class="price-input" placeholder="Price" v-model="entry.price" />
            <span class="x-sign" v-on:click="removeEntry(index)>X</span>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
```